# Breakpoint on full page picture issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've got an issue about the resizing of a picture, in a full page div.

The thing is that it seems some breakpoints are missing (for 15 inch screens for example). The picture is croped at the bottom and resizes well for smaller screen.

Here is the link : http://mango-assurances.com/

Any ideas ?

Cheers,

Loïc

Comment: Please include the relevant code here to reproduce your issue, this isn't a site to debug your pag.

Comment: You might have to clarify _"cropping"_. I'm not seeing any cropping at any screen size (I'm looking at the mango image with arrows coming out of it).

Comment: Page looks fine for me on all viewport sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is 1200x848 large... with your header and cookie notification area you're running out of vertical heigh and the "cropping" is natural viewport restrictions.

This UI is totally acceptable and you don't need to change it.  (Remember the user could have a browser that is smaller-windowed than full screen.)

But if you do then you have 2 options:  1) Use a smaller image, & 2) restrict the width (or height) of the image with a CSS restriction (`max-width:800px`) - like this...

```
<img src="img/mango-hd.png" class="img-fluid center wp wp-7 mt80 animated
  fadeInUp" style="max-width:800px">
```

Comment: Hi Vino, thanks for everything, i admit my question was pretty stupid but you helped me !

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question - SO is all about asking questions, please feel free to ask as you wish.  (If you're happy with the Answer, remember to up-vote and mark as correct answer.)